# Can't run Cypress Open

Tags: cypress

I recently took over a cypress project; running on windows.  The first time I installed, all was working.  Now, subsequent to upgrading node/electron/chrome, I can't open cypress with any command.  Here's what I tried:

- Delete node_modules directory in my project.
- `npm init`  Answered with all defaults.  node_modules directory is present but empty.
- `npm install cypress --save-dev` (from [the doc][1]).  This populated my node_modules, but installed cypress in my account (users) directory.
- `node_modules\.bin\cypress open`  That reported:

  - It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 3.1.1
  - Verified Cypress: [in my users dir]
  - Opening Cypress...

At that point I can see cypress in my process list, but the UI never shows.  I can run headless tests normally, so I'm OK from a CI perspective, but I still want to open the UI with my tests locally.  I can launch the cypress executable in my user dir and then open my project root directory manually, but can't run an open command normally.  The `scripts` section of `package.json` doesn't seem to be designed to accept a path to an exe with params.

Is there another way to call open that I'm missing?

Comment: If you are not getting any error and UI is opened in the taskbar but GUI is not visible then you can Shift + Right Click on the icon in the Toolbar and then click Maximize - that should bring the Window into the foreground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you upgrade the Electron version that Cypress uses? Cypress uses Electron 1.8.2 which is significantly behind the latest, and Cypress does not currently support newer versions of electron. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3568) for more info.

Comment: Yes.  Guess that's the problem, though it's strange I can launch it directly and it works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution**: Go to your project directory which you installed cypress, in your `package.json` update the cypress version to the **latest** , look at the [releases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#3-8-3) versions link, or just install the latest from cli:

```
npm install cypress@latest --save-dev
```

Reopen again and verify:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress open
//OR
npx cypress open
```

Answer (score 2):

try starting with debugging enabled:

```
DEBUG=cypress:* ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't use command npm to open cypress neither,
but command npx works well.
So you can try this in your visual studio code: npx cypress open

Answer (score 0):

Using this in my code solved the issue

cypress (folder) -->support --> index.ts

**add this:**

import './commands'

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {

// returning false here prevents Cypress from failing the test

return false

})

Answer (score -1):

Didn't work for me as well. I got the same error. I've created new folder in the repo.

- Run npm init -y
- Run npm install --save-dev cypress
- Then go to ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open

And boom the error.
I've workaround it by adding:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress open"
  }
}
```

into package.json
and run cypress with npm run test